# Show perpendicular guidelines while using gradient tool

Tags: adobe-photoshop, gradient, adobe-lightroom

On lightroom, when you're using the gradient tool, you're able to see 3 guidelines showing the start of the gradient, middle and end of the gradient while creating the gradient itself.

Is there any way to show that in photoshop too?

Note: The same lines also appear in the gradient tool on camera raw, but I wish to use it outside camera raw for masking and such.

An example for what I'm referring to:

[image: An example for what I'm referring to]

Comment: Can you attach a screenshot of what you're referring to?

Comment: @WELZ done. It appears in camera raw too.

Comment: Photoshop doesn't have this functionality.

Comment: If you draw it with the Gradient tool, the start point is where you start dragging and the end point is where you stop dragging. Middle point is in the middle of those two points.

Answer (score 1):

No, you can not do this in Photoshop.

It would be possible to make a tool that does this with the API though. It is a lot of work and would require a specially dedicated person to do this. But its not impossible by any means.

Comment: Hm, do you have more information about making new tools for PS? I always thought it's impossible (and there're no existing 3rd party tools for PS to my knowledge)

Comment: @SergeyKritskiy no its possible its just a bit covoluted to use the API. You just end up spending about a 100 times more time than youd want. But you can essentially do whetever you want just up to you how much work you can be able to put into it. But ike i said its really cumbersome so that is the rewason why its not done.

Comment: Ok but can you give documentation for creating new tools, what API are you referring to? Even C++ plugins are limited to their own processes

Comment: @SergeyKritskiy There is no documentation for such things since adobe does not make it easy. But all your plugin really needs is a way to adress what pixel you are over and how to do a gradient. And the API does that you can then hijack the window drawing routines of your os and draw whatever you like on top of the window. All you really need to communicate is the gradient drawing locations.

Answer (score 1):

### Use Camera Raw Filter Gradient or Layer Style Gradient Overlay

The Photoshop gradient equivalent is to set your parameters first.

[image]

For even greater non-destructive control, you can use the Layer Style Gradient Overlay. This gives you even greater control than you get in with the Lightroom tools, non-destructively which you can later use for layer masks etc by rasterising.

[image]

I know you said you want to do it outside of Camera Raw. But wasn't sure if you meant the filter also. Maybe there is something here that can help?

1. Create your first colour as a standard Layer
2. Go to `Filter > Camera Raw Filter` <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>
3. Select the Gradient Filter <kbd>G</kbd>
4. Unselect "Mask" if it's selected.
5. Now create a colour from colour selection that's now available.

This is how you can use a lightroom style gradient experience.

---

[image]

[image]

### The Result:

[image]

Comment: Hmm isince the OP know thsi works in Camera raw as per comment. I dont think this feels like in photoshop. But yes your right this is sortof in Pohotoshop +1 (so not to wste bounty), but pushing the boundaries of definition.

Comment: Yeah, wasn't too sure or if they had tried this method, so thought I would throw it out there anyway.

Comment: Unfortunately, when I meant camera raw I meant both, standard and filter. You see, I wish to use it in places where you can't use camera raw such as a layer's mask or other smart filter's masks

Comment: No problem. There’s a lot of room for improvements with Photoshop. It’s a shame Adobe bought out Macromedia, which was there only real competition. As a result the product doesn’t really improve at the rate we would expect. Photoshop UI could do with a boost, with the tool you mention amongst others.